# Why is my TeX file treated as a PostScript document in arXiv submission, with error 'no tex files found'?

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

While submitting my paper (produced using [Overleaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overleaf)) to [arXiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv), I found that the main TeX file (named *ms.tex*) is treated as a [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) file.

Then, after processing the files, I get the following line in the AutoTeX log:

```
[verbose]: <ms.tex> is of type 'Postscript'.
```

Then, after a few lines, I get the error:

```
[verbose]:  No tex files present, going to hope we can process as a postscript or dvi only package.
```

Then, in the preview of the paper, I could only see the figures and no text of the paper. What is wrong with the TeX document?

Comment: are the first two characters of the file `%!` ?

Comment: Yes, the first line of the TeX file is '%! TeX program = xelatex'. This line is written on the sample file provided by the journal.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`%!` is the magic marker used to identify PostScript used by the Unix/Linux `file` program and other tools.

Some editors (but not Overleaf) use a `% !TeX` syntax comment to control the processing done on the file. They all (now) allow a space between the `%` and the `!` to avoid misinterpretation as PostScript.